# IBM MQ : JMS message consumer fails receive when message has correlation id

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I'm receiving messages in a JMS message consumer as in (pseudo-code):

```
loop
   Message msg = MessageConsumer.receive(timeout);
end-loop
```

For some reason this fails if the received message has a correlation id but works fine if the message doesn't.

I'm producing messages like this:

```
TextMessage textMsg = session.createTextMessage("<myTestMsg  type=\"TEST\"></myTestMsg>");
if (addCorrelationId) {
    textMsg.setJMSCorrelationIDAsBytes(new byte[]{(byte)49});
}
jmsProducer.send(textMsg);
```

This is the error I see in the  in the consumer side logs:

```
July 19, 2016 6:15:04 PM CEST[Queue Service thread] com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.messages.WMQReceiveMarshal
A received message could not be correctly parsed.

EXPLANATION:
The message with messageID = '414D512064657620202020202020202012048D5720072E04' and correlationID = '310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' could not be correctly parsed. The last successful data read from the message was at position '192' in buffer '
0000:  5246 4820 0000 0002 0000 00c0 0000 0111    RFH ............
0010:  0000 04b8 4d51 5354 5220 2020 0000 0000    ....MQSTR   ....
0020:  0000 04b8 0000 0020 3c6d 6364 3e3c 4d73    ....... <mcd><Ms
0030:  643e 6a6d 735f 7465 7874 3c2f 4d73 643e    d>jms_text</Msd>
0040:  3c2f 6d63 643e 2020 0000 0074 3c6a 6d73    </mcd>  ...t<jms
0050:  3e3c 4473 743e 7175 6575 653a 2f2f 2f6d    ><Dst>queue:///m
0060:  7971 7565 7565 3c2f 4473 743e 3c54 6d73    yqueue</Dst><Tms
0070:  3e31 3436 3839 3434 3930 3438 3738 3c2f    >1468944904878</
0080:  546d 733e 3c45 7870 3e31 3436 3839 3434    Tms><Exp>1468944
0090:  3933 3438 3738 3c2f 4578 703e 3c43 6964    934878</Exp><Cid
00a0:  3e49 443a 3331 3c2f 4369 643e 3c44 6c76    >ID:31</Cid><Dlv
00b0:  3e31 3c2f 446c 763e 3c2f 6a6d 733e 2020    >1</Dlv></jms>  
00c0:  3c6d 7954 6573 744d 7367 2020 7479 7065    <myTestMsg  type
00d0:  3d22 5445 5354 223e 3c2f 6d79 5465 7374    ="TEST"></myTest
00e0:  4d73 673e 3037 2d31 3954 3138 3a31 353a    Msg>07-19T18:15:
00f0:  3034 2e36 3838 2b30 323a 3030 222f 3e00    04.688+02:00"/>.
0100:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0110:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0120:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0130:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0140:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0150:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0160:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0170:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0180:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0190:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
01a0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
01b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
01c0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
01d0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
01e0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
01f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0200:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0210:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0220:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0230:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0240:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0250:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0260:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0270:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0280:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0290:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
02a0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
02b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
02c0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
02d0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
02e0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
02f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0300:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0310:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0320:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0330:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0340:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0350:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0360:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0370:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0380:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0390:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
03a0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
03b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
03c0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
03d0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
03e0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
03f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0400:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0410:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0420:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0430:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0440:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0450:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0460:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0470:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0480:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0490:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
04a0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
04b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
04c0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
04d0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
04e0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
04f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0500:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0510:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0520:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0530:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0540:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0550:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0560:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0570:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0580:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0590:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
05a0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
05b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
05c0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
05d0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
05e0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
05f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0600:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0610:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0620:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0630:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0640:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0650:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0660:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0670:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0680:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0690:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
06a0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
06b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
06c0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
06d0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
06e0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
06f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0700:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0710:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0720:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0730:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0740:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0750:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0760:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0770:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0780:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0790:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
07a0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
07b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
07c0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
07d0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
07e0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
07f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0800:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0810:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0820:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0830:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0840:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0850:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0860:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0870:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0880:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0890:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
08a0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
08b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
08c0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
08d0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
08e0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
08f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0900:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0910:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0920:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0930:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0940:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0950:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0960:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0970:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0980:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0990:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
09a0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
09b0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
09c0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
09d0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
09e0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
09f0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0a00:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0a10:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0a20:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0a30:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0a40:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0a50:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0a60:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0a70:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0a80:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0a90:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0aa0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0ab0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0ac0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0ad0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0ae0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0af0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0b00:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0b10:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0b20:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0b30:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0b40:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0b50:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0b60:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0b70:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0b80:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0b90:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0ba0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0bb0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0bc0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0bd0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0be0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0bf0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0c00:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0c10:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0c20:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0c30:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0c40:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0c50:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0c60:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0c70:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0c80:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0c90:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0ca0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0cb0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0cc0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0cd0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0ce0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0cf0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0d00:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0d10:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0d20:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0d30:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0d40:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0d50:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0d60:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0d70:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0d80:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0d90:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0da0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0db0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0dc0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0dd0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0de0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0df0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0e00:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0e10:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0e20:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0e30:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0e40:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0e50:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0e60:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0e70:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0e80:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0e90:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0ea0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0eb0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0ec0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0ed0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0ee0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0ef0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0f00:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0f10:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0f20:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0f30:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0f40:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0f50:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0f60:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0f70:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0f80:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0f90:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0fa0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0fb0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0fc0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0fd0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0fe0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
0ff0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    ................
'
```

What am I doing wrong?

My message consumer is MQ Classes for JMS (IBM MQ client v8.0.4).

### UPDATE

The problem goes away if I use [msg.setJMSCorrelationID](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSCorrelationID(java.lang.String)) rather than [msg.setJMSCorrelationIDAsBytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSCorrelationIDAsBytes(byte[])) when the message is produced.

Comment: could this be related ?: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT08928

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458417/ibm-mq-how-to-know-reason-for-dead-letters

Comment: @Alex:  As to the first one: Nope. My producer doesn't set any properties. As to the second one that is my own post. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check this: [MQHRF vs MQHRF2](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/jms/31307-invalid-message-received-in-remote-mq-what-will-be-the-possible-cause)

> It seems that your message consumer only supports Websphere MQ's raw
>   MQSTR format and does not support MQHRF2 (an enhanced format with
>   headers in addition to the body of the message). Due to this, you see
>   MQHRF2 headers in your message ( e.g. "" "" ...).

I think the sender must set the target client to 1 (ie: MQ).

```
Queue myQueue = session.createQueue("queue:///myQueue?targetClient=1");
```

Comment: That's some old stuff from the days of MQ Series v6. That property is deprecated. Still you may have point.

Comment: sorry for the quick cut&paste of url.. I still remember a while back having to use the clientarget to allow JMS with MQ...

Comment: Yeah. I'll have to look into that. My only trouble with your answer is that both my producer and consumer are JMS. Still I'm interested in compatibility with native MQ consumers as well so I need to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0):

A Correlation ID is 24 bytes long.  So why don't you explicitly create a Correlation ID that way?

```
TextMessage textMsg = session.createTextMessage("<myTestMsg  type=\"TEST\"></myTestMsg>");
if (addCorrelationId) {
    textMsg.setJMSCorrelationIDAsBytes(new byte[24]{
    (byte)49,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,
    (byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,
    (byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x00});
}
jmsProducer.send(textMsg);
```

> 07-19T18:15:04.688+02:00"/>

Also, what is with the garbage at the end of the message?

Comment: 24 bytes. Really?  I can find nowhere in the JMS spec where it says so. I don't doubt that is the case for IBM MQ but I would expect JMS to shield me from such differences. My code is expected to be vendor agnostic. Wrt the garbage at the end of the message: Now, *there's* a point. I've wondered that myself. :-)

Comment: I didn't say JMS spec said the CorrelId was 24.  What I said was the IBM MQ MD's Correlation ID is EXACTLY 24 bytes.  I've been working with IBM MQ since it was launched.  Absolutely, correlId is 24 bytes. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q097470_.htm